# why am i getting none at the end of my output in the following code and how to avoid it?

Tags: python, class

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, initialage):
        self.age= initialage
        print(self.age)
        print(initialage)
    def increaseby1(self):
        self.age += 1
        print(self.age)
a=A(5)
print(a.increaseby1())
```

Comment: tl;dr: `increaseby` does not return anything so by default it returns `None`.  You are printing the return value of `increaseby` when you shouldn't have to.  Remove the `print` statement for the last line of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't have a return value, meaning it implicitly returns `None`. To avoid that, either don't wrap the function call in a `print` statement or return the value you intended to print inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Because your function doesn't return anything, it just prints age. And since you try to print it's returning value, which is None, it prints None

I suppose you want to print just the `self.age`, and you want to get rid of printing `None`.
The solution to this problem would be:
`a.increaseby1()` instead of `print(a.increaseby1())`

So you print the value you want in the function, and then just call it, instead of printing it's returning value, which is None

or

`return self.age` instead of `print(self.age)` in your `increaseby1` function. This way your function will increment the value and the return it, so when you call your function in `print` statement it will print `self.age`

Comment: Except that is the code perfect? Or it can be improvised?

Comment: I suppose you want to print just the `self.age`, and you want to get rid of printing `None`.
The solution to this problem would be:
`a.increaseby1()` instead of `print(a.increaseby1())`

So you print the value you want in the function, and then just call it, instead of printing it's returning value, which is None

or 

`return self.age` instead of `print(self.age)` in your `increaseby1` function. This way your function will increment the value and the return it, so when you call your function in `print` statement it will print `self.age`

Comment: `def pal(s):
    if s==s[::-1]:
        print('palindrome')
    else:
        print('not a palindrome')
pal('s')`  even though i am not returning anything here, there is no 'none' in the output. can someone explain this? @Bhargav Rao @VooXe